# Rewrite within location with a new root/alias - Nginx

Tags: nginx, location, url-rewriting, alias, root

My folder structure is as follows:

```
/www
    /api.domain.tld
    /app.domain.tld
```

The API contains the system it self and APP implements the API via HTTP.

I want to create an Nginx server for app.domain.tld that also contains an "virtual directory" for API.

You can contact the API likes this: http://api.domain.tld/method/api.json

But it would be great if the API can be contacted like this also: http://app.domain.tld/api/method/api.json without copying something into APP, but keep those two "systems" separated.

What I have for now:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/app.domain.tld;
    index index.php index.html;


    server_name app.domain.tld;


    location ^~ /api {
        alias /var/www/api.domain.tld;


        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri = 404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }


        rewrite ^/api/([a-z]+)/api.json$ /api.php?method=$1 last;
    }


    location....
    location....
    location....


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does now works as expected.

The rewrite does not work at all. I can get api.domain.tld/index.php but when it needs to use the rewrite, it will not work.

I have tried several things. Either I get 404 or 403 with this error:
directory index of [path] is forbidden

Can someone come up with a better solution that actually works?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You should change SCRIPT_FILENAME path:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/app.domain.tld;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ ^/api/(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /www/api.domain.tld/public/$1;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }    
}
```